# Enigmail doesn't work with 15.10

Tags: thunderbird, email, enigmail

I just updated to 15.10 and enigmail doesn't work anymore. Before, when sending an email, it asked me for the passphrase, and everything was fine.

Now, it just says "Error - wrong passphrase" and cannot send the message, when I turn on signing.

Encryption works perfeclty fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the package `pinentry-gnome3` solved the issue for me.